# Geodesic multiple ring buffer in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geodesic, buffer

The Buffer tool in ArcGIS 10.5 allows for the creation of geodesic buffers, however, I am unable to find that option for the Multiple Ring Buffer. I have 10 areas around which I need to create 6 geodesic ring buffers (huge areas so quite a difference regarding area) and I'd like to use the multiple ring buffer tool to avoid having to clip each ring. Any ideas how to best achieve this?

Comment: What about to use a python script?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to do that

Comment: BTW, I tested both buffers with geodesic method and multi-ring buffer for the same shapefiles for the same multiple distances and the results are same for both cases. So I think multiple ring buffer will do the purpose as geodesic distances.

Comment: I did that, too, and in the CRS (Winkel III) and the scales I am using (about 2,000 km diameter) I am getting differences in area calculation around 200,000 km2. I assume it's a mix of CRS and dimensions, which is why I chose to use geodesic buffering. But many thanks for testing!